# Grunt only running one task

Tags: gruntjs

This is my first time trying to set up Grunt. I'm seeing that only one out of two defined tasks is running at a time. If I switch the default task from 'watch' to 'sass', only the sass task will run (and vice versa). So that makes me think the code for both tasks is correct, but maybe some other configuration setting or registerTask type function is needed.

Is there anything wrong with my Gruntfile.js that would cause this issue?

## Gruntfile.JS

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
// --- SASS

        sass:{
            dist:{
                options:{
                    style:'expanded',
                    sourcemap:'none',
                },
                files:{
                    'style.css':'SCSS/style.scss'
                }
            }
        },

// --- WATCH

        watch:{
            css:{
                files: '**/*.scss',
            }
        },
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    // grunt.registerTask('default',['sass']);
    grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
}
```

Comment: I assume you want the watch task to trigger the sass task, yes? If so specify the sass task in a [tasks key (array)](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#tasks) in the watch object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
watch: {
    css: {
        files: '**/*.scss',
        tasks: ['sass'],
    },
},
```

That's it, just add the `sass` task to `watch` and whenever the `files` change, the `task` will be run.

Alternatively, don't register `watch` as a task at all! You can set `sass` as the default grunt task, and simply type `grunt watch` to kick off the watch task.

Now if you're using something like the Nuget package in VS I understand registering watch, but if that's the case I suggest trying out Powershell, at least for the ease of installing new packages, node modules, getting a debug message for JS errors, etc.